# check/ Getting a session name with php

Tags: php

I have two Domain site (Exmp: A & B) and two database, 
function site A is for a payment method, so if a custumer buy a product, it will be direct for login first and 
The site B is as a frontpage (web interface) only. 
My question is :  how can I get or check the session value FROM Site A and show the session_name in my  interface website when the user is open my web at the same time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're facing 2 problems:

1. The `session-id` is probably stored on a `cookie`, and the browser will not send a cookie originated from domain A to domain B (unless you're talking about the same domain).
2. Even if you're able to have the session-id on both domains, for the data to be persistent across 2 sites, you're gonna need a shared session `storage` configured.

Possible solutions:

1. Pass the `session-id` over the URL as query-string parameter (not recommended for many reasons and has to be configured accordingly in your `php.ini`).
2. As for the `storage`: the common approach is to use a `database` as your session storage provider (hence making is 'shared').

Also, you may reconsider the use of `session` altogether, if you're only doing basic redirection maybe you can pass the data over a regular GET or POST request.

Comment: thanks haim for answer,
 I have change the directory on my website.
 the domain is. exmp: www.abc.com (as the interfacee) . 
 and payment method directory is, www.abc.com/authentic/yourstore.php (/'authentic').
 but still use diffrent database in the same server. 

question: can I set, the session_cookie ? 
 to display a session_name in www.abc.com on this case?? thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm not quite sure i understand your question, but if your 'redirection' is only to a sub-directory on the same domain then you shouldn't have any problem, you should be able to access the same session data from both directories.